# Is it possible to specify a range for numbers randomly generated by mvrnorm( ) in R?

Tags: r, random, range, simulation

I am trying to generate a random set of numbers that exactly mirror a data set that I have (to test it). The dataset consists of 5 variables that are all correlated with different means and standard deviations as well as ranges (they are likert scales added together to form 1 variable). I have been able to get `mvrnorm` from the `MASS` package to create a dataset that replicated the correlation matrix with the observed number of observations (after 500,000+ iterations), and I can easily reassign means and std. dev. through z-score transformation, but I still have specific values within each variable vector that are far above or below the possible range of the scale whose score I wish to replicate.

Any suggestions how to fix the range appropriately?

Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: How about replacing each out-of-range value with the range boundary value?

Comment: Getting the right data generating process require serious modeling effort. Finally, The range of a gaussian distribution is directly linked to the choice of mean and variance

Comment: If after z-score transforms you find that your data extremes are very different, then maybe your original data is not normally distributed?

Comment: this discussion might be of use to you:  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-generate-a-normal-distribution-with-mean-1-min-0-2-max-0-8-td3481450.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a sample that does "exactly mirror" the original dataset, you need to make sure that the marginal distributions and the dependence structure of the sample matches those of the original dataset.
A simple way to achieve this is with resampling

```
my.data   <- matrix(runif(1000, -1, 2), nrow = 200, ncol = 5)  # Some dummy data
my.ind    <- sample(1:nrow(my.data), nrow(my.data), replace = TRUE)
my.sample <- my.data[my.ind, ]
```

This will ensure that the margins and the dependence structure of the sample (closely) matches those of the original data.

An alternative is to use a parametric model for the margins and/or the dependence structure (copula). But as staded by @dickoa, this will require serious modeling effort.

Note that by using a multivariate normal distribution, you are (implicity) assuming that the dependence structure of the original data is the Gaussian copula. This is a strong assumption, and it would need to be validated beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and information! This is really good advice. What is typically the process for determining the dependence structure of a dataset? Thanks again!

Comment: This is a statistical modeling question. The keyword would be copula. You might find useful information and references here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/37951/27403.